# i want to make update in two table in one button button1_click

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have two tables, `Projects` and `ProjectImages`. I want to get the image_id from the second table. This is my current code:

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Waves;Integrated       Security=true;");

```
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Update_Project", con);
    com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectID",Label1.Text);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectName",txtName.Text);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VideoUrl", txtName.Text);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Notes", txtName.Text);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date",DateTime.Now.Date);
    WavesEntities wee = new WavesEntities();
    var query = from p in wee.Project_Images
                select p.img_Id;
    SqlCommand com1 = new SqlCommand("UpdateProjectImages", con);
    com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;


    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@img_id", query.AsEnumerable());
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@img_path", con);
    con.Open();
    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
```

the error:

> No mapping exists from object type
>   System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] to
>   a known managed provider native type.

Comment: Could you just do the two updates in one stored procedure?

Comment: the problem i can not get img_id parameter

Comment: `com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@img_id", query.AsEnumerable());` is the problem, i'm not really sure what you expect this to do but you are trying to ad en `IEnumerable<T>` as a SQL parameter.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** After seeing your edit, your problem might be a different issue, but still, you can try what I answered.

**EDIT 2:** Your parameters in command 2 are referencing the command 1. Change your parameters to this:

```
com1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@img_id", query.AsEnumerable());
com1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@img_path", con);
```

Your problem is that you cannot use the same SqlConnection for two "alive" SqlCommands.

Change your code to something like this:

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Waves;Integrated Security=true;"))
{
    con.Open();

    using(SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Update_Project", con))
    {
        com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectID",Label1.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectName",txtName.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VideoUrl", txtName.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Notes", txtName.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date",DateTime.Now.Date);
        WavesEntities wee = new WavesEntities();
        var query = from p in wee.Project_Images
                    select p.img_Id;
    }

    using(SqlCommand com1 = new SqlCommand("UpdateProjectImages", con))
    {
        com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;


        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@img_id", query.AsEnumerable());
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@img_path", con);
        con.Open();
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: the problem is what can i get the Img_id to but incom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@img_id", query.AsEnumerable());

Comment: Following the comment from @Ben Robinson, you cannot pass query.AsEnumerable() as the value of the parameter. If your intention is to pass an integer value as the parameter value, you can try this instead: Convert.ToInt32(query).

Comment: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[System.Int32]' to type 'System.IConvertible'. not yet working this the error

Comment: Can you please post the definition of Project_Images?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to get the `img_id` for the respective `ProjectID` from `wee.Project_Images` method and then pass the single retrieved value (`img_id`) to the stored procedure for update. So your `query` would become

```
 var query1 = from p in wee.Project_Images
              where p.ProjectID == Label1.Text
              select p.img_id;

 com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@img_id", query);
```

Please note that you can not pass an `Enumerable()` object as a parameter to a stored procedure. Also don't forget to use `using` statement for `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` object for better disposal of resources after it's been used.

Comment: Debug and check what the result of `var query` and what's being passed in as parameter for `img_id`.